# jQuery changing attribute and changing it back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make all links on the page unaccessible until the user clicks a button.

```
$('a').attr('href','#');

$("#button-yes").click(function(){
    $('a').attr('href',function(){
        $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a var outside your function that says something like:

```
button_clicked = false;
```

Then use this to disable all links

```
$('a').click(function(){
   if(!button_clicked){
      return false;
   }
});
```

Returning false will cause the link to do nothing.

Answer (score 6):

How about just keeping track of state instead of rewriting all the hrefs?

```
var buttonClicked = false;

$('a').click(function(){
  if(! buttonClicked) {
    return false;
  }
});

$("#button-yes").click(function(){
    buttonClicked = true;
});
```

Comment: I think this solution comes because it is more effective and with less work and has solved the problem. Thats why the lazy programmers are the best :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to stash the value of the href so that it can be recovered later.  I'll stash the href value into the rel attribute.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('rel', $(this).attr('href'));  //store the href values
    $(this).attr('href', '');  //clear the href values
});

$("#button-yes").click(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('rel'));  //recover the href values
    });
});
```

This is a simple approach, but it leaves the address in the rel attribute.  A clever user might find and use this to circumvent your button, so here's another approach as suggested by @rsp.

```
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).data('link', $(this).attr('href'));  //store the href values
    $(this).attr('href', '');  //clear the href values
});

$("#button-yes").click(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).data('link'));  //recover the href values
    });
});
```

By storing the href using .data(), the link address is a little more obscure so users shouldn't be able to circumvent the button as easily (though disabling JavaScript will sidestep this completely).

Comment: Your example doesn't disable the links - they still work. You store the href attribute in the rel attribute but you don't remove the href attribute. Also, for storing arbitrary data on dom nodes you can use .data() in jQuery.

Comment: @rsp: Good call.  I forgot to disable the links as I went.  I realize data may be better, but there is something to be said for rel - for instance, the link is still human readable in the code, so you can verify where the link is supposed to go.  In this case, that may be a detriment, so I will post an alternate version that uses .data()

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example would be to hijack the click event of all links:

```
$('a').live('click.disable', function() {
    return false;
});

$("#button-yes").click(function() {
    $('a').die('click.disable');
});
```

(see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A6QPn/) but anyone can right-click the link and open it in new tab or something like that.

Another example would be to store the href attributes as data and restore them later:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('href', $this.attr('href'));
    $this.attr('href', '#');
});

$("#button-yes").click(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('href', $this.data('href'));
    });
});
```

(see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eQDdQ/) and here the links are just not working because they all point to '#' on the current page.

Another example would be to basically do the same but remove the href attribute altogether making the links look like normal text until the button is clicked:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('href', $this.attr('href'));
    $this.removeAttr('href');
});

$("#button-yes").click(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('href', $this.data('href'));
    });
});
```

(see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gmLTP/)